# Ping and timer command batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am novice when it comes to batch scripting. can you help me with my problem? I want to ping certain IP address and color will change depending on the status of the network. Now my problem is I dont know correct syntax for when network is down, timer will start while continous pinging and will change window color after reached certain timeout and vice versa. Thank you in advance.

```
:top
TITLE TEST
PING 10.44.32.12 -n 1 -l 1 -w 2000  | FIND "TTL="
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (SET OUT=CE  & echo Request timed out.) ELSE (SET OUT=0E)
color %OUT%
ping -n 2 -l 10 127.0.0.1 >nul
GoTo top
```

Comment: I know it's not exactly relevant, but the C# Ping class in `NetworkInfo` can better handle your case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=net-6.0

Comment: I don't know if this can help you [Script that pings and displays the status of multiple network devices](https://www.reddit.com/r/Batch/comments/v88gob/comment/ibqbf24/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: Just to mention a pretty good alternative that could be compiled on your own if you need changes is vmPing https://github.com/R-Smith/vmPing

Answer (score 1):

So you want it to wait for a few timeouts in a row before changing the colour. You need to implement a counter and change the colour when the counter reaches a certain threshold. Reset the counter when there is a reply:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set fail=0
:top
TITLE TEST
PING -4 10.44.32.12 -n 1 -l 1 -w 2000  | FIND "TTL="
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
  set /a fail+=1  
  echo Request timed out [%fail%].
) ELSE (
  set fail=0
  SET OUT=0E
)
if %fail% gtr 5 (
  color CE
  if %fail% gtr 10 color 4E
) else (
  color 0E
)
ping -n 2 -l 10 127.0.0.1 >nul
goto :top
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it was almost the same as my code above, however my problem is for example. once network is down it will automatically set color to orange, then after 5 minutes of pinging and is still down, color will turn to red.

Comment: simply add another `if`. See my edit.